# Is it possible to use Yocto Tool offline?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to build a image for Rpi2 using Yocto. The issue is I have slow net. do_fetch process are talking quite a lot time. So is there a way I could download all the packages it needed from a friends' internet connection and they put them in my system and use those instead of fetching them from the internet? I know it looks for packages at the SRC_URL defined in the .bb files.

Comment: You can check the following sections of the manual [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#how-does-the-yocto-project-obtain-source-code-and-will-it-work-behind-my-firewall-or-proxy-server) and [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#setting-up-effective-mirrors)

Comment: @Nayfe I think you can quote the relevant sections of the manual and make it an answer.

Comment: @Nayfe That's helpful!